# undefined method `put_file' for #<Net::SFTP::Session:0x00000000b70138> (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

I found the following problem to use net/sftp:
undefined method `` `put_file' for #<Net::SFTP::Session:0x00000001b40298>
(NoMethodError) ``

```
sftp.rb:17:in `block in <main>': undefined method `put_file' for #<Net::SFTP::Session:0x00000000b70138> (NoMethodError)
    from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-sftp-2.0.5/lib/net/sftp/session.rb:939:in `call'
    from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-sftp-2.0.5/lib/net/sftp/session.rb:939:in `block in do_version'
    from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-sftp-2.0.5/lib/net/sftp/session.rb:939:in `each'
    from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-sftp-2.0.5/lib/net/sftp/session.rb:939:in `do_version'
    from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-sftp-2.0.5/lib/net/sftp/session.rb:909:in `when_channel_polled'
    from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.1.4/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:311:in `call'
    from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.1.4/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:311:in `process'
    from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.1.4/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:214:in `block in preprocess'
    from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.1.4/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:214:in `each'
    from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.1.4/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:214:in `preprocess'
    from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.1.4/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:197:in `process'
    from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.1.4/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:161:in `block in loop'
    from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.1.4/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:161:in `loop'
    from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.1.4/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:161:in `loop'
    from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-sftp-2.0.5/lib/net/sftp/session.rb:802:in `loop'
    from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-sftp-2.0.5/lib/net/sftp/session.rb:787:in `connect!'
    from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-sftp-2.0.5/lib/net/sftp.rb:32:in `start'
    from sftp.rb:16:in `<main>'
```

But the module could be loaded without problem:

```
2011.07.08|17:12:07~/lin/Ruby>irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'net/ssh'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'net/sftp'
=> true
irb(main):003:0>
```

By the way, my RUBYLIB is:

```
2011.07.08|17:15:33~/lin/Ruby>echo $RUBYLIB
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/
```

Thanks!
  Dan

P.S:

```
require 'net/ssh'
require 'net/sftp'


   host="localhost"
   src_file="/etc/services"
   dst_file="~/services"

   Net::SFTP.start(host, ENV["USER"]) do |sftp|
     sftp.put_file(src_file, dst_file)
   end
......
```

Answer (score 1):

Net::SFTP [does not have a `put_file` method](http://net-ssh.rubyforge.org/sftp/v2/api/classes/Net/SFTP/Session.html). See the [full documentation](http://net-ssh.rubyforge.org/sftp/v2/api/) for Net::SFTP.

Did you perhaps mean `sftp.upload` or `sftp.upload!`?

Comment: No, I really meant the sftp.put_file method. Is it possible a RUBYLIB setting problem or something else?

Comment: But there _isn't_ a `put_file` method on SFTP objects. Are you following an example you could link to?

Answer (score 1):

Check your version. Net::SFTP 2 doesn't have `put_file` anymore. Use `upload` instead.